# Loading signal only on a DIV

Tags: jquery, html, loading

I have this code that will call a page to a div when the radio button is selected, but sometimes, it takes 4 or 5 secounds to load, because it as a big query...

Is there a way to put a loading signal while the div loads the content ?
thanks :)

```
   $('#button-radio-1').change(function(){
                var valor = $(this).val(); 
                $.post('mostrar_whois.php',{valor: valor}, function(data){
                $('#pesquisa').html(data)
                });
            });
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try add a "spinner" img to your div, and remove it as soon as the post action is complete. Like this:

```
$('#button-radio-1').change(function(){
                var valor = $(this).val();
                $('#pesquisa').html('<img src="spinner.gif" />');
                $.post('mostrar_whois.php',{valor: valor}, function(data){
                $('#pesquisa').html(data);
                });
            });
```

Comment: Not working, it loads the image, but right after, it loads the mostrar_whois.php, and spends same 3, 4 secounds to load it :)

Comment: I don't get it, isn't that what you are looking for? Have the spinner visible until the mostrar_whois.php finishes execution and return data?

Comment: no, it takes a little until the data loaded is complete, and i wanted to have it in that time :)